# Extracting data from Cosmos DataBase using python

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

#I want to read the data stored in Cosmos DataBase in which I have the url, key, DB_Name, Collection_Name, and the SQL Query

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
import JSON

url = 'xxx'
key = 'xxx'
client = CosmosClient(url, credential=key)    #The error on this line

database = client.get_database_client('DB_Name')
container = database.get_container_client('Collection_Name')

for item in container.query_items(
        query="SELECT * FROM c",
        enable_cross_partition_query=True):
    print(json.dumps(item, indent=True))
```

#The error I'm facing is "binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (85) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4"

Comment: It looks like you are using incorrect key. Your key should be a base64 encoded string and should look something like `rc4IUGqPQpXXQJ6VVpfgbHfzJSyG3D4KmnOvj6BKI83SJVntRzACudnzZEjcIW9HdYkZlBpDaoWIi1Tw30S5Rw==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (85) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4"

Your base64 input is probably incorrect, according to the error.

Every three input bytes are converted by the base64 encoding into four ASCII characters from a small set.

To Interaction with Cosmos DB, you will need **URI of account**, and one of its **account keys**. The database account URI and primary master key are filled into two environment variables using the Azure CLI snippet below. Which you can access in python code (you can also get this from portal).

```bash
RES_GROUP=<resource-group-name>
ACCT_NAME=<cosmos-db-account-name>

export ACCOUNT_URI=$(az cosmosdb show --resource-group $RES_GROUP --name $ACCT_NAME --query documentEndpoint --output tsv)
export ACCOUNT_KEY=$(az cosmosdb list-keys --resource-group $RES_GROUP --name $ACCT_NAME --query primaryMasterKey --output tsv)
```

Sample `ACCOUNT_KEY` : "`vQvn5qlCrM6Kcqvhl68EjK2cVWKSNW12Tvq53KIFavR6XflFQaZb9BxipBOyG0Iv9CivJJWGZOe3Anvvx1YukA==`"

After getting `ACCOUNT_URI` and `ACCOUNT_KEY` you can access it in python.

```py
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient

import os
URL = os.environ['ACCOUNT_URI']
KEY = os.environ['ACCOUNT_KEY']
client = CosmosClient(URL, credential=KEY)
```

Reference: [cosmosdb with python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-sql-api-python#update-your-connection-string)